# iOS app with realm.io crashes while retrieving string properties

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift, realm

I'm encountering problems while trying to read data from my realm into a tableView.

My model looks like this:

```
class DiaryEntry: RLMObject {

    dynamic var date = NSDate()
    dynamic var word = ""
    dynamic var text = ""
    dynamic var imagePath = ""
    dynamic var mood: Int = 6
}
```

to retrieve the entries I followed the tableView-Example from [realm.io](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift/TableView/TableViewController.swift)
As soon as I try to access any string property the app crashes while the original example works as expected.

```
let entry = array[0] as DiaryEntry

println(entry.description)

header.lblDate?.text = entry.date.description
header.lblHeadline?.text = entry.word   // App crashes here
```

The log outputs:

```
DiaryEntry {
    date = 2015-01-22 16:08:41 +0000;
    word = blabla;
    text = asdfads;
    imagePath = ;
    mood = 6;
}
table.cpp:2431: [realm-core-0.88.0] Assertion failed: type == col_type_StringEnum
0   trust                               0x000000010e55e956 _ZN7tightdb4util9terminateEPKcS2_l + 454
1   trust                               0x000000010e679896 _ZNK7tightdb5Table10get_stringEmm + 518
2   trust                               0x000000010e4c6174 _ZNK7tightdb8RowFuncsINS_5TableENS_8BasicRowIS1_EEE10get_stringEm + 84
3   trust                               0x000000010e4c10fb _ZL12RLMGetStringP13RLMObjectBasem + 59
4   trust                               0x000000010e4c550f ___ZL17RLMAccessorGetterP11RLMPropertycP8NSString_block_invoke_8 + 47
5   trust                               0x000000010e456860 _TFC5trust19DiaryViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView22viewForHeaderInSectionSi_GSqCSo6UIView_ + 2384
6   trust                               0x000000010e4570f2 _TToFC5trust19DiaryViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView22viewForHeaderInSectionSi_GSqCSo6UIView_ + 66
7   trust                               0x000000010e549bdb -[STCollapseTableView tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:] + 155
8   UIKit                               0x000000010f1e2d5e -[UITableView _delegateViewForHeaderInSection:] + 45
9   UIKit                               0x000000010f1e63b4 __96-[UITableView _sectionHeaderView:withFrame:forSection:floating:reuseViewIfPossible:willDisplay:]_block_invoke + 97
10  UIKit                               0x000000010f1615ce +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 65
11  UIKit                               0x000000010f1e6261 -[UITableView _sectionHeaderView:withFrame:forSection:floating:reuseViewIfPossible:willDisplay:] + 531
12  UIKit                               0x000000010f1e6b50 -[UITableView _sectionHeaderViewWithFrame:forSection:floating:reuseViewIfPossible:willDisplay:] + 85
13  UIKit                               0x000000010f1c5c66 -[UITableView _updateVisibleHeadersAndFootersNow:] + 2582
14  UIKit                               0x000000010f1c7354 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3777
15  UIKit                               0x000000010f1dce3c -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
16  UIKit                               0x000000010f169973 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ef7bde8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ef70a0e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ef7087e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010eede63e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010eedf74a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
22  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ef9e6bd _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy + 489
23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110499f64 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110499b25 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1045
25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011045ce5d __CFRunLoopRun + 1901
26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011045c486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
27  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000112a939f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
28  UIKit                               0x000000010f0f0420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
29  trust                               0x000000010e4b99ee top_level_code + 78
30  trust                               0x000000010e4b9a2a main + 42
31  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111366145 start + 1
32  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
IMPORTANT: if you see this error, please send this log to help@realm.io.
```

As you can see the object description looks quite good but accessing a property isn't working as expected.

I've tested realm 0.89 as well as 0.90.

**EDIT:** I've found a workaround! When I do a simple `DiaryEntry.allObjects()` in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` it works as expected o0

Comment: Hi Daniel, it's quite odd that it's looking for a string enum property... We're looking into this.

Comment: @jpsim Thanks, I've also noticed that the Integer value is messed up: `entry.mood is: 1421948128`

Comment: We have a fix under review for this: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/1412. Thanks for reporting!